# Understanding an extract from "Phonétique française"

Tags: phonétique

I'm reading Phonétique française by B. Malmberg and there is one thing I don't understand:

> Une tendance populaire  à réaliser le groupe /n/ + /j/ (dans *panier*)
>   comme [ɲ] implique que le phonème /ɲ/ (*baigner*) se scinde en deux
>   unités phonologiques. **Dans la mesure où cette tendance se généralise,
>   le phonème /ɲ/ disparaît du consonantisme français en même temps que
>   le son  [ɲ] se fait plus fréquent.**

What does the bolded part mean? When the sound [ɲ] becomes more frequent, the phoneme /ɲ/ will dissapear? I can't make any sense of it... 
Merci d'avance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ayant eu cette discussion avec des Italiens, car il m'était impossible de distinguer au premier abord des mots qui ne se distinguent que par /nj/ et /ɲ/, je ne suis pas surpris d'entendre que la différence entre /nj/ et /ɲ/ a quasiment disparu en français. Je me souviens avoir fait la [liste des paires critiques](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1098?m=39913059#39913059) chez Cosette il y a quelque temps de cela. Apparemment ces quelques paires n'ont pas été suffisantes pour maintenir une distinction entre /nj/ et /ɲ/ en français. Personnellement je ne fais généralement pas de différence entre « minions » et « mignon » par exemple.

Le jour où plus personne ne fait la différence entre /nj/ et /ɲ/ (ce qu'envisage l'auteur de l'extrait), il n'y aura plus de raison de distinguer deux phonèmes. Dans ce cas, étant donné que la prononciation [ɲ] semble prendre le dessus (probablement car moins articulée), elle sera simplement devenue la réalisation standard de la séquence /nj/. Tout comme [tχ] est la réalisation standard de /tʁ/, le phonème /χ/ n'ayant aucune raison d'être distingué en français.

Comment: C'est marrant, j'ai discuté récemment avec un espagnol de la distinction tranchée qu'il faisait entre les terminaisons d' *España* et celle d' *Hispania* que j'avais du mal à percevoir.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is indeed a bit vague, but I suppose the author means that /ɲ/ tends to formally disappear, replaced by /nj/, but as it has a sound extremely close to  [ɲ], somehow you could say that every /nj/ has sort of become /ɲ/.

Well, I'm not sure I'm very much clearer than the book...

Comment: Actually, it says that the sound /nj/ is disappearing, being replaced by /ɲ/. But since there is no longer any distinction between /nj/ and /ɲ/, you can just represent both these phonemes both /nj/, doing away with the phoneme /ɲ/